Register repository as public service in a bundle
In converting an existing Symfony app (version 7.0) to a custom bundle I'm encountering an error caused by custom entity repositories not getting loaded in the container. Debugging the container seems to show that I've configured these repositories correctly however.
The error
When trying to instantiate a repository from my bundle via EntityManager::getRepository(MyEntity::class); I get the following error:
The "TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository" entity repository implements "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface", but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".
I'm fairly confident that I've configured and tagged this service correctly in the bundle's services.xml file. The weird thing is, if I explicitly configure this service in the application's services.yaml file I do not get this error and the repository is instantiated correctly.
Details
First, here is the relevant snippet from the bundle's services.xml:
<services>
    <service
        id="tbd_custom.my_entity_repository"
        class="TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository"
        public="true"
        autowire="true"
    >
        <tag name="doctrine.repository_service" />
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine"></argument>
    </service>

    <!-- Alias -->
    <service 
        id="TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository"
        alias="tbd_custom.my_entity_repository"
    />
</services>

If I instantiate this repository directly in the bundle with $repo = new MyEntityRepository(); it works, but when instantiating a repository in an application with the more typical pattern of having the EntityManager construct it, I get the error mentioned above:
/** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
$em->getRepository(MyEntity::class); // throws exception

As I mentioned above, if I configure this repository in an app's services.yaml like so I do not get an error:
# my_app/config/services.yaml
services:
    TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository:
        autowire: true
        public: true
        tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']


Debugging
When I run the debug:container command to inspect this repository when I've configured it in the bundles services.xml I get the following output:
 // This service is a private alias for the service orc_m365_oauth.orc_user_repository

Information for Service "tbd_custom.my_entity_repository"
============================================================

 ---------------- --------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- --------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       tbd_custom.my_entity_repository
  Class            TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository
  Tags             doctrine.repository_service
  Public           yes
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   no
  Usages           TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository
                   tbd_custom.tbd_some_service
                   .service_locator.CF2y05q
 ---------------- --------------------------------------------------

 ! [NOTE] The "TBD\CustomBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the
 !        container was compiled.

If I run the same command after configuring the service in the app's services.yaml I do not get the warning about the service being removed when the container was compiled. This tells me that something about the way I'm configuring the repo in the bundle's services.xml is not right. However I haven't been able to figure out what. Maybe this is a red herring.
Background
At work, we have an authentication setup for apps we use internally that gets replicated across multiple apps that I'd like to be able to bundle up and reuse more easily. The components of this bundle include a controller, customer authenticator, services, entities and their repositories.
So far I've been able to get all of this functionality working as a bundle with the one exception of this error. The workaround I've been using for now is to configure that repository manually in the app's services.yaml.
Alternatives
In trying to debug this I looked for examples of public Symfony bundles that provide custom entities and repositories. It seemed to me that these are somewhat rare. In fact I wasn't able to find a bundle where entity repositories were included as services in the digging I did.
This all makes me think that maybe the problem here is that I'm trying to do too much with my bundle and that perhaps there's an alternative approach that I haven't considered. That said, keeping the services and entities contained within the bundle would be preferable if there's a way to make it work.

I'm not sure which symony version u are using. But shouldn't your alias config be inverted? https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/service_container/alias_private.html#aliasing

Symfony version for my app is 7.0 -- updated question to include that. Regarding the alias for the service, aliasing the snake_case service ID with the class name like in my example is to allow the service to be autowired even if it were a private service. In the the doc you linked, the aliasing is reversed because that example shows the opposite purpose -- fetching the service from the container directly by using a snake_case id: $container->get('app.mailer');
